# Change header and footer on window.print()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I'm printing a html page with window.print() function. I'm looking for a way to change the default header and footer witch appear on every page. For header i want to delete it, and for footer  i want to have a image that should appear on every page. Is there any javascript/jquery function or css code to do that?
I've read a lot of stuff and nothing should solve my problem.

Comment: Research print stylesheets using `media="print"`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `@media print`

ex:

```
@media print {
  header {
    display: none
  }
  footer > img {
    display: block
  }
}
```